# Ifuturz UploadPdf causes huge system.log with Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: magento-1.9

In the system.log I have thousands of entries saying:
**ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home//public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/uploadpdf/uploadpdf.phtml on line 10**

So the code is:

```
<?php
$current_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$productid = $current_product->getEntityId();

$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
            //echo "SELECT * from ifuturz_uploadpdf WHERE product_id='$pid'     ";
            $readresult=$write->query("SELECT * from ifuturz_uploadpdf WHERE product_id='$productid' ");
            $entityid = $readresult->fetchAll();
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($entityid);
            $eid =  $entityid[0]['pdf_file'];   <======= LINE:10
            if($eid!='')
            {
            ?>
                <div class="collateral-box">
                    <div class="head">
                            <h4><?php echo $this->__('PDF Downloads') ?>    </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php

                for($i=0; $i<count($entityid) ;$i++)
                {
                    //echo     Mage::getBaseUrl('media')."pdffiles/uploadedfiles/".$entityid[$i]['pdf_path'];
                    $front = $entityid[$i]['pdf_file'];
                $pdfnm = $entityid[$i]['pdfname'];
                //$pdfnew = explode('/',$pdf);
                //$pdfexp = $pdfnew[8];
                //$pdffinal = str_replace('.pdf','',$pdfexp);

                if($pdfnm == "")
                {
                    $ext = explode(".", $front);
                    echo '<li style="font-family: verdana;margin-bottom: 15px;margin-left: 10px;"><a target="_blank" href="'.$entityid[$i]['pdf_path'].'">'.$ext[0].'</a><br /></li>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<li style="font-family: verdana;margin-bottom: 15px;margin-left: 10px;"><a target="_blank" href="'.$entityid[$i]['pdf_path'].'">'.$pdfnm.'</a><br /></li>';
                }
            }
        }
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($entityid);
        ?>
```

I guess there should be an extra if statement that catches the 0 exception right ? But how to do this properly in php ?

Comment: Never use Ifuturz's extension(very poor quality work they do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this line

```
$eid =  $entityid[0]['pdf_file'];
```

look like this

```
$eid =  isset($entityid[0]['pdf_file']) ? $entityid[0]['pdf_file'] : '';
```

Comment: This indeed did the trick ... many thanks for saving my MegaBytes !

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you copy `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/uploadpdf/uploadpdf.phtml` to your theme folder in order to over-ride it.

Then, you need to take a look at what `$entityid` actually returns. `var_dump` the variable within the template.

Looking at how it's being called, it should return an array, where each entry has a ['pdf_file'] key to another array.

To check for this in PHP I'd probably look at two commands.

Firstly, is this an array? `is_array` - I would assume it is, as you're getting undefined offset, and not a message about manipulating something other than an array.

Secondly, does the offset exist? `array_key_exists`, something like:

```
if (array_key_exists('0', $entityid)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the response of this code :

```
$readresult = $write->query("SELECT * from ifuturz_uploadpdf WHERE 'product_id='$productid' ");
 $entityid = $readresult->fetchAll();

            echo "<pre>";
print_r($entityid);

            $eid =  $entityid[0]['pdf_file'];
```

Check the response if the return array have a value at its "0" index or not.

For check this condition you can use this code :

```
array_key_exists('0', $entityid)
```